# C: Trouble with GMP pointers in a struct

Tags: c++, c, glib, gmp

I'm fairly **new to c** and I'm implementing a DHT.
For that, I have to store node IDs in a list.

Node IDs are < 2^160 whole numbers(thus resulting in me using GMP), but I'm setting 123 as an ID here to keep the example clean.

I am able to set the Node's ID just fine, and I also verify it with `mpz_out_str`. When I iterate over it with `g_slist_foreach` and print the ID, it outputs a HUGE number, which is completely irrelevant.

I suspect it has something to do with the **cast** from `gpointer` to `Node`, or that I may be storing it incorrectly(very **new to pointers**)

Code:

```
#include <glib.h>
#include <gmp.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
  mpz_t *node_id;
} Node;

void print_iterator(gpointer item, gpointer prefix) {
  // Also, since the item is of type gpointer,
  // It has to be casted back to Node.
  Node *node = (Node *)item;
  // outputs a HUGE, completely random number.
  mpz_out_str(stdout, 10, node->node_id);
  printf("\n");
};

GSList *add_node(GSList *nodes) {
  Node *node = malloc(sizeof(Node));
  mpz_t id;
  mpz_init(id);
  char *f = "123";
  mpz_set_str(id, f, 10);
  node->node_id = &id;
  // prints correct value
  mpz_out_str(stdout, 10, node->node_id);
  nodes = g_slist_append(nodes, node);
  return nodes;
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
  GSList *nodes = NULL;
  nodes = add_node(nodes);
  g_slist_foreach(nodes, print_iterator, "‑‑>");
  return 0;
}
```

Relevant links:

https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Singly-Linked-Lists.html
https://gmplib.org/manual/

Comment: Don't use both C and C++ tags. If you used a C++ compiler, you should get an error telling you that you are using wrong pointer types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `node->node_id = &id;` your node_id points at a local variable. When `add_node` returns, `id` is destroyed and your pointer is dangling. Dereferencing it results in Undefined Behavior.

A simple solution is to store the id in `Node` rather than storing a pointer to it.

```
typedef struct {
  mpz_t node_id;
} Node;
```

Comment: Cheers for the quick response. However, I would like to store it in a pointer as most GMP functions require pointers, and it would be slightly more annoying to handle that if I store it without one.

Comment: @Aarnav Then you will have to allocate memory to store the node id and free it when you're done.